# How to navigate with key down and up in nested lists in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, nested-lists

I'm trying to implement arrow down and up in two different lists, while in one of them it has childrens. I have two unordered lists and into one of them I have another ngFor that runs on its children(nested list). Key down should handle all options including children.

```
<input (keyup)="keyDown($event)"/>
<div>
  <h4>Filters Names</h4>
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let filter of filters; let i = index;" [class.activeSearchLink]="i === linkIndex"> 
     {{filter.name}}
        <div *ngFor="let subFilter of filter.subFilters">
           {{subFilter.name}}
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
<h4>Filters Values</h4>
<ul>
  <li *ngFor="let value of filters.values; let i = index;"[class.activeSearchLink]="i=== linkIndex"> 
    {{item.name}}
   </li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

code:

```
keyDown(event) {
  switch (event.keyCode) {
      case 38: 
                this.linkIndex--;
              break;
      case 40: 
                this.linkIndex++;
              break;

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is something related to the "accesibility". Depending on what do you want exactly, you don't need a special javascript code to handle it.

Some useful links:

[What is current best practice for moving focus in an accessible menu (in html), tab or arrow keys?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26287162/what-is-current-best-practice-for-moving-focus-in-an-accessible-menu-in-html)

[Keyboard-navigable JavaScript widgets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/Keyboard-navigable_JavaScript_widgets)

[How do I make div or li accessible through Up/down arrow keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63473515/how-do-i-make-div-or-li-accessible-through-up-down-arrow-keys)

There is an example : [Navigation Menubar Example](https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/example-index/menubar/menubar-navigation)